# Special characters support in web applications app.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a requirement to create database application user logon with all the special characters for example `~A1\{<°!§$%&/a()'";=?`_:[/>}]*`

and save this user name and password in the WCF app.config and web application web.config connectionstring key to connect DB from application.

Tried in C# with System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape() and getting the following errors,

- Semi colon

  Getting "Keyword not supported error" while saving to the config file
- If password starts with double/single quote

  Getting "'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 71.'" while saving config file
- If use other special characters like § °

  Getting "Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 14, position 125." when updating the ConnectionString

Tried creating new logon with the below query,

```
CREATE LOGIN sa1 WITH PASSWORD=N'~A1\{<°!§$%&/a()'";=?`_:[/>}]*', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[tempdb], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

- When use the above script, getting syntax error near single quotes

Could someone help on this to handle these special characters in SQL & Application level.

Comment: This isn't about "special characters" - `web.config` is an XML document which means a *few* of these characters must be escaped, like `"`, which would be mistaken for an end quote and \, which is the escape character itself. If you save the file as UTF8 (the default), all the others are just text as far as XML is concerned

Comment: `Tried creating new logon` this has nothing to do with ASP.NET or XML - in *SQL* strings are escaped differently. In this case, only `'` needs to be escaped by using another `'`, eg `'It''s escaped'`

Comment: Why is are SQL accounts with such weird passwords used anyway? The *safest* option is to create Windows accounts, even for services, and add the Windows logons to SQL Server. A WCF service can connect to the database using its own service account. This way there won't be any reason to store a password anywhere. It's possible to create [service accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-service-accounts) both at the local machine and the domain level,  active only if the *service* is active, so that *no* password has to be specified, anywhere.

Comment: My customers are in different region and they are using different characters to configure SQL account and used in the application config files. Some characters are giving error. So they want to support all the characters basically.

Comment: That doesn't affect any of the comments I posted. `web.config` uses UTF8 so regions have no effect. Only specific characters need escaping in XML or SQL. There's no need to use SQL accounts unless the clients are in different *Windows domains* or there's no domain at all. The safe option is to use a service account

Comment: `used in the application config files.` that means they risk *losing* those passwords. That's why it's safer to use the application's account to connect to the database

Comment: The application config files will be encrypted after updating the connectionstring key.

Comment: The config files can still be read by applications on the same machine. Never mind rotating the password, especially if you use multiple web servers. Wouldn't it be better if there was no password to leak at all?